# Combining two event handlers into one (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have extracted a function from two event handlers, however I was wondering if the event handlers themselves could be combined:

```
// when to hide/show the Submit link (select is changed)
$('.season select').on('change', function() {
    var TVContainer = $(this).parents('.submission');
    getTVData(TVContainer);
});

// when to hide/show the Submit link (validate on input changed)
$('.season input').on('keyup', function() {
    var TVContainer = $(this).parents('.submission');
    getTVData(TVContainer);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the handler a separate function. To make sure you get the right `this` in that `function`, use `bind(this)`.

```js
function handler() {
    var TVContainer = $(this).parents('.submission');
    getTVData(TVContainer);
}

// when to hide/show the Submit link (select is changed)
$('.season select').on('change', handler.bind(this));

// when to hide/show the Submit link (validate on input changed)
$('.season input').on('keyup', handler.bind(this));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could extract your handlers to another function:

```
function handler () {
    var TVContainer = $(this).parents('.submission');
    getTVData(TVContainer);
}

$('.season select').on('change', handler);

// when to hide/show the Submit link (validate on input changed)
$('.season input').on('keyup', handler);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can combine your selectors and combine your events - especially since you can't type into a select. Give it a try.. you'll potentially want to handle for change events being called after exit from input.

```
$('.season select, .season input').on('change keyup', function() {
    alert("change or keyup called");
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lbztf7eh/

Comment: OP just wants to combine the callbacks. this adds both events to both selectors OP doesn't want that